# How to get the milliseconds to the next hour

Tags: java, date, datetime

I want to the milliseconds to the next hours. For example

Now time -> 10:01:23 2nd Oct, 2018, Want remaining milliseconds to 11:00:00 2nd Oct, 2018.

The Now time is dynamic, it can be 23:56:56 2nd Oct, 2018 and next hour is at 00:00:00 3rd Oct, 2018.

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(startDate.getMillis());
    calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR, 1);
```

I was trying something like this, but it is adding 1 hour to the startDate. But I want exact next hour.

Any help is welcomed.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since Java8, you can use [`java.time.LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html):

```
    LocalDateTime start = LocalDateTime.now();
    // Hour + 1, set Minute and Second to 00
    LocalDateTime end = start.plusHours(1).truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.HOURS);

    // Get Duration
    Duration duration = Duration.between(start, end);
    long millis = duration.toMillis();
```

Running just now (2018-10-02T18:44:48.943070 Peking time) I got 911 056 milliseconds.

Comment: As a matter of taste, instead of `.withMinute(0).withSecond(0)` I’d probably write `.truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.HOURS)`. It will also get rid of milliseconds and microseconds, so will be more accurate.

Comment: @OleV.V. Thats great! Can you please help me edit it :)

Comment: Done @Sun hope I understood your intention correctly

Comment: @OleV.V. Thanks. I'm going to check it

Comment: This code fails if your implicitly intended time zone experiences an anomaly in its wall-clock time. For example, [North Korea recently changed its offset-from-UTC by half an hour](https://news.sky.com/story/north-korea-resets-clocks-by-half-an-hour-to-match-south-11358551). Lacking any concept of time zone or offset-from-UTC, the `LocalDateTime` class **cannot** represent an actual moment, is *not* a point on the timeline. Use `ZonedDateTime` instead for such work.

Answer (score 3):

A simple arithmetic approach:

```
long hourInMillis = 60 * 60 * 1000;
long startDateInMillis = startDate.getMillis();
long millisSinceLastHourChange = startDateInMillis % hourInMillis;
long millisToNextHourChange = hourInMillis - millisSinceLastHourChange;
```

works since Java 1 ;-)

EDIT
This approach doesn't take DST or similar changes into account.

Comment: If you can use Java 8, I think the Java 8 solution is better because the code expresses the intent better. I upvoted this as well because it works in Java before Java 8/without Joda-Time, and in any languages in which you can somehow get the milliseconds.

Comment: The [shown](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52602168/2838289) Java8 solution is an OO approach whereas this one is an arithmetic one. Since the arithmetic complexity is low the code is still easy to read. But in fact it has very low prerequisites. The OO solution is because of the well defined API easy to read.

Comment: No, the OO solution, if performed properly, will deliver correct results. Your solution fails during an anomaly experienced in the intended time zone, such as [North Korea changing its offset by half-an-hour](https://news.sky.com/story/north-korea-resets-clocks-by-half-an-hour-to-match-south-11358551). Your code fails in such a case. In other words, an hour is not always ( 60 * 60 * 1,000 ) milliseconds long.

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

Hours on the clock are *not* always an hour long.

Leverage a time zone to handle such cases.

```
Duration
.between(
    zonedDateTime_Now ,
    zonedDateTime_FirstMomentOfHourLater 
)
.toMillis()
```

## Beware of anomalies

If you want to account for real-world anomalies in wall-clock time used by your intended time zone, you must specify a time zone. This means using the `ZonedDateTime` class.

An hour is not always an hour. For example, [North Korea recently adjusted its offset-from-UTC by half-an-hour](https://news.sky.com/story/north-korea-resets-clocks-by-half-an-hour-to-match-south-11358551). This means one hour will last only 30 minutes during the adjustment jump. This example of North Korea is only one of the most recent examples. Politicians around the world show a surprising penchant for redefining their time zone(s).

### Time zone

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 2-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now( z ) ;
```

Add an hour.

```
ZonedDateTime hourLater = now.plusHours( 1 ) ;
```

Truncate to the hour.

```
ZonedDateTime firstMomentOfNextHour = hourLate.truncatedTo( ChronoUnit.HOURS ) ;
```

### Elapsed time

Calculate elapsed time as a [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) object.

```
Duration d = Duration.between( now , firstMomentOfNextHour ) ;
```

The *java.time* classes use nanosecond resolution, but you asked for milliseconds. So understand that there is data-loss involved in reporting milliseconds.

```
long milliseconds = d.toMillis() ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

A `java.time` solution using [`ZonedDateTime.until`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#until(java.time.temporal.Temporal,java.time.temporal.TemporalUnit)):

```
ZonedDateTime startDate = ZonedDateTime.now();
LocalDateTime nextHour = startDate.plusHours(1).truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.HOURS);
long msUntillNextHour = startDate.until(nextHour, ChronoUnit.MILLIS);
```